# Mocha test silenty fails because SUT forgot to complete a promise

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I've created a simple test case whose complexity is above what I can understand.

This test reproduces a case, where the SUT forgets to complete an internal promise, to which the test has a handle. By doing this, the test manages to complete without any report.
Unfortunately mocha does not report any issue with that.

I've tested multiple parameters, none did help to really fail this test:

- `--async-only`
- `--forbid-pending`
- `--allow-uncaught`

Also tested the describe function to be `async`, the it function is `async` of course. Didn't work and was rather a blind guess.

Also tested `await Promise.all([secondPromise , firstPromise]);`. Did not change the silent exit

This is the test

```
describe("stupid me promise", () =>{

    it("why does this not work?", async () => {

        let secondResolve: (val:unknown) => void;

        let secondPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {secondResolve = resolve});

        let firstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { console.log("I do something, but forget to resolve secondPromise"));

        console.log("Awaiting a promise, that never completes");
        await secondPromise;
        // also tried:
        //await Promise.all([secondPromise, firstPromise]);

        console.log("This line here never gets hit. The test exists silently")
        expect(true).to.be.false;

    });

});
```

The detail here is: I await the secondPromise and for now ignore the first one.

Should mocha wait for the secondPromise and either hang forever of fail with a timeout if a timeout was set (I use `--no-timeouts`)?

I would never write this kind of test, but during testing my SUT I accidentally introduced a regression in the SUT and wondered, why the test was silently swallowed

This test never passes the `await secondPromise` and simply ends.
Does somebody know why?

Here is my vs code configuration if that matters

```
        {
            "name": "mocha single test",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": [
                "--grep",
                "why does this not work?",
                "--color",
                "-r",
                "ts-node/register",
                "${workspaceRoot}/test/**/*.spec.ts",
                "--no-timeouts"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
```

If I understand the behavior correctly: The awaited promise is never fulfilled. The rest of the code is dead because nothing will ever get there, ok. But why does mocha end the test? Even when I use `--forbid-pending` the tests simply ends.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in the docs [here](https://mochajs.org/#command-line-usage)

> In v3.0.0 or newer, a parameter passed to this.timeout() greater than
> the maximum delay value will cause the timeout to be disabled. In
> v8.0.0 or newer, this.enableTimeouts() has been removed. **Warning: With
> async tests if you disable timeouts via this.timeout(0) and then do
> not call done(), your test will exit silently**.

So I am in an async test and I was using `--no-timeouts` and the bold text happened.

When I remove the `--no-timeouts` flag, the test will fail.

Still though, does not explain, why this happens